# How can I view through the water surface without reflection?

Tags: visible-light, water, reflection, sun

I am searching for a possibility to see the shallow grounds of water without reflections on the surface.
I am sailing in an area where there are reefs and shallow coral patches which can be dangerous for the boat and its passengers.
Navigating with sight is important. My thought was to see the scenario from above could increase the field of view.
Therefore I mounted a camera on my mast top but the images are disappointing. As my sailing zone is the tropics, the sun stands mostly in the zenith, exactly behind the camera and I can only see the reflections of the sun.
Is there any possibility to exclude these sun rays with technology like thermal, ir or a filter or any other?
Virginia

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics.SE! Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts. Every post you make is already "signed" with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you want to change the default userxxxxxxx displayed name you can do so in the *Edit profile and settings* tab in your profile page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can exclude all reflection, a polarizing filter will help. But why not have a camera in a waterproof case on the bottom or side of your boat, the higher the camera, the more reflection you will get,

Comment: The point is to be able to see _distant_ underwater hazards. I don't know where the OP is sailing, but I've sailed in the Bahamas in a bay that was a couple of miles across and nowhere more than about five feet deep. An under water camera, not more that five feet above the bottom, would not be much help seeing into the distance even if the water was crystal clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the low-tech way. glue a round piece of clear plastic over the end of a 6" to 8" diameter plastic pipe about two feet long. attach handles to the open end so you can position it with your hands. to use, dip the closed end into the water below the level of the waves and look down through the pipe. This will give you a clear view below the surface of the water, without waves, ripples and reflections.

The high-tech solution is to buy a *backup camera* as used on cars so the driver can see what's behind the car while backing up. Seal the camera up so it is waterproof and tie it to the end of a stick, then submerge it. Then you can watch what's under the water on the screen. These usually operate on 12VDC.

Comment: Your low tech way is more suitable for short distance viewing. For this purpose we have depth sounder or fish finder where we can see the ground under the boat. For previewing a potential reef we must focus more in the distance.

Comment: The underwater camera will also only be able to see some feet in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a polarizing filter? You can test the idea for cheap by removing one of the lenses from a pair of polarized sun glasses, and jury rig it to your camera with duct tape. Be sure that the sunglass lens is oriented the same way it would have been oriented if you were wearing it. If you turn it sideways, it will make the glare *worse* instead of making it better.

Or,... How much money are you willing to spend? If money is no object, then I propose that you procure a tethered drone that can fly out ahead of your intended course, and look straight down from that vantage point. :-)

---

> a polarising filter...may be suitable for little reflections but not for this massive glares

@user2485259, I don't understand the difference between "little reflection" and "massive glare."

The filter can not know or care about the size of the patch of water that is reflecting the light. And, it can't know or care about the brightness of the reflection. It only filters out whatever rays are horizontally polarized (assuming it's mounted in the proper orientation, of course.)

The fraction of the light that is horizontally polarized when it reflects off the surface of the water will depend on the angle at which it is reflected. At one ideal angle, it will be totally polarized. The further from that angle, the smaller the polarized fraction. (Google for "Brewster's Angle" to learn more.)

The polarizer isn't a perfect solution, especially since waves and ripples will cause your camera to see light that was reflected at many different angles, but it should be *some* help.  If it wasn't, then there would be no market for polarized glasses.

Comment: I have not tried a polarising filter yet. I have one on my DSLR but the effect is decent. may be suitable for little reflections but not for this massive glares.

Comment: @user2485259, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot distinguish between the reflected sunlight coming off of the water and the sunlight reflected from the underwater.

An interface reflection (like the air-water interface) will occur for all wavelengths of light. Sunlight is partially polarized, but a polarizer will probably give enough contrast for your use case. It is possible to suppress reflections with an anti-reflective coating, but in your case, the coating would have to be applied to the surface of the water - which is not practical.

As suggested in other answers, there are other solutions - such as putting the camera underwater (avoid the interface) or by somehow shading the water you want to see through (keep the interface dark). You might also be able to use your own light source and somehow block sunlight from your camera, but that is probably impractical.

There may be many other great solutions as well, but the key takeaway is that the sunlight from the water reflection will get filtered the same way as the sunlight you want from underwater.